# Correct preposition for 'workplace'

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions

Should I say

> Eating is not allowed in the workplace

or

> Eating is not allowed at the workplace

when eating is, in fact, not allowed anywhere near the PC in an office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a situational use and you can use whatever fits 'workplace' the best. If the workplace were out in an open field at a park (maybe you're park rangers), it may sound weird to say:

> Eating is not allowed *in* the workplace

But if the workplace is in an office like it is for most people, then you can literally be *inside* the workplace. In this case it makes complete sense to say

> Eating is not allowed in the workplace.

Conversely if you work in an office with a break room and its acceptable to eat in the break room but you're referring to it being forbidden to eat ***at*** your desk, then you should go with:

> Eating is not allowed at the workplace

I'd suggest temporarily replacing `workplace` with whatever that workplace really is, and use the preposition that fits best in that case.